# Geopandas geodataframe copy with where clause causes geometry issues

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely, fiona, geocube

**Question up front:**
What is likely happening here, where when I take copy of the dataframe with a where clause present that there is an apparent break in the geometry, as implied by the linestring error (assuming non-closed polygon), and null pointer reference. Why isn't that break in geometry represented in all operations, such as outputting to a shapefile?
Is there an alternate strategy that might avoid this?

**Info:**
I have a geodataframe, built from a selection of shapefiles, that has been working fine when I output to shapefile, csv, geopackage, and other general spatial operations such as adding new columns with calculations, grouping, etc. This geodataframe has a geometry column where each record should contain a square. Ie, I have grid setup, with each individual grid unit bounded by its own polygon.

I have just recently started to try to contour the contents. First I export the df2 to a shapefile, then rasterise the polygons from the shapefile using geocube (*which is a wrapper for rasterio*) as recommended by @snowman2 in a number of other posts. This works, assuming I'm not taking a subselection from the dataframe first. The issue is, however, that I do need to take a subselection of the dataframe, and this is causing what I can only assume to be geometry errors.

**Example:**
This works to rasterise the entire dataframe, but includes a lot of data I don't want.

```
import numpy as np
import os
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import json
from geocube.api.core import make_geocube
from osgeo import gdal
from osgeo.gdalconst import *
from osgeo import osr
from numpy import *
from osgeo import ogr

    df2 = df1.copy() #This line is the one to watch - This one works.

    # Make a raster using the shapefile - could go straight from dataframe
    print('Making raster')
    input_geopackage = os.sep.join([output_dir, os.path.basename(sabre_out_dir)]) + 'impact.shp'
    out_grid = make_geocube(
        vector_data=input_geopackage,
        resolution=(-30, 30),
    )
    out_grid["Brn"].rio.to_raster(os.sep.join([output_dir, os.path.basename(out_dir)]) + 'Brn.tif')
```

Now, when I limit the selection of the dataframe by using the following, I get the errors below. Do note, however, that I can still output df2 as a shapefile, and it will open in ArcGIS Pro, and QGIS 3.12.2, and it will show the polgons in a grid as expected.

```
df2 = df1.copy().where(df1['FIRE_CNT'] > 0)
```

**Errors:**

```
Making raster
IllegalArgumentException: Points of LinearRing do not form a closed linestring
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Repos\Cloud\Cloud\process_output_raster.py", line 360, in <module>
    resolution=(-29, 29 ),
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\geocube\api\core.py", line 90, in make_geocube
    categorical_enums=categorical_enums,
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\geocube\vector_to_cube.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.geobox = geobox_maker.from_vector(self.vector_data)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\geocube\geo_utils\geobox.py", line 200, in from_vector
    mapping(box(*vector_data.total_bounds)), crs=crs
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\shapely\geometry\geo.py", line 19, in box
    return Polygon(coords)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\shapely\geometry\polygon.py", line 243, in __init__
    ret = geos_polygon_from_py(shell, holes)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\shapely\geometry\polygon.py", line 509, in geos_polygon_from_py
    ret = geos_linearring_from_py(shell)
  File "shapely\speedups\_speedups.pyx", line 401, in shapely.speedups._speedups.geos_linearring_from_py
ValueError: GEOSGeom_createLinearRing_r returned a NULL pointer  
...
```

**Notes:**
Changing / removing .copy() doesn't make the error go away. I am taking a copy so that any further calculations dont change the data in the original dataframe.

It's actually really quite difficult to provide sample code for this, so I'm most interested in understanding why this might be happening so I can approach a fix.

**Additional Attempts:**
The following, where I reference the dataframe directly rather than using a shapefile in the middle has the same issue. I wanted to rule out the shapefile driver as the issue.

```
    print('Making raster')
    #input_geopackage = os.sep.join([output_dir, os.path.basename(sabre_out_dir)]) + 'impact.shp'
    out_grid = make_geocube(
        #vector_data=input_geopackage,
        vector_data=df1.where(df1['FIRE_CNT'] > 0),
        measurements=["Brn"],
        resolution=(-30, 30),
    )
    #out_grid["mdTmBrnT"].rio.to_raster(os.sep.join([output_dir, os.path.basename(out_dir)]) + 'Brn.tif')
    out_grid.rio.to_raster(os.sep.join([output_dir, os.path.basename(out_dir)]) + 'Brn.tif')
```

Comment: I think we need a geocube tag as I am just seeing this. The issue occurs in the `total_bounds` method of geopandas. Are you able to provide the original data?

Comment: I'm actually not sure I ever came up with a resolution for this one. I can't remember clearly, but I believe I had to take an entirely different approach.   
   
A geocube tag would be helpful.

Comment: Makes sense. If you are still interested in a solution and are able to provide the input file, I can take a look later.